# border-left and border-right not showing up in browser

Tags: html

```
here is the header Section code

  #headerSection {
            background-color: 2D487E;
            color: white;
            }
```

the background color of the borders are supposed to be dark blue...

```
  <section id="headerSection">
   <p class = "center"><img src= "images/nashcc.jpg" 
     class =  "nashPic"
     alt="Nash Community College" 
     title="Nash Community College"
     width = "250px"/>
   <span class = "title">Nash Community College</span><p>
  </section>
```

Comment: Your code works when I paste it in to a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nundskat/ (I just changed to color of the border to make it more visible). So this is most likely a problem with how your CSS is being loaded, a conflict with some other style, etc.

Comment: Thank you, will look around.

Comment: ryantdecker, I don't know anything about jsfiddle.net but I just changed the red to the #EEEEEE and it does not come up at all, just like in my browser...just trying to figure it out...can you run that again in the jsfiddle with the #EEEEEE...would really appreciate it.

Comment: #eeeeee is almost white. Are you sure it's not coming up? Post a link to your fiddle

Comment: that might be where I am messing up as I am looking for a dark blue border....geeze....got to go look around some more. :(

Comment: the text color in the header is coming out but the absent borders are still AWOL

Comment: if you want dark blue, try something like #02116E - when you use #EEEEEE it's still working, but depending on your monitor, the background color, etc, it just blends in because it's a very light gray.

Comment: I wish I could but this is an assignment and the colors are specified...just don't understand why the borders are not coming out on either side...just a slow go for me...thank you for all your help. :)

Comment: There is no border set in the code shown.

Comment: @TammyWinstead where do want to set border ? on headerSection or nashPic class ?? the background color you set its  dark blue color code. but you missed the # before it.  background-color: #2D487E;

Answer (score 0):

on headrSection that background color you set not working you need a # before that code. And one small mistake you forget to close the p tag after span.

```css
    body{
    margin:0;

   }
    #headerSection {
        background-color: #2D487E;
        color: white;
       
        }
  .nashPic {
        vertical-align: -275%;
        padding: 0px;
        border-right: solid 10px #EEEEEE;
        border-left: solid 10px #EEEEEE;
        }
```

```html
<section id="headerSection">
 <p class = "center">
  <img src= "https://www.nashcc.edu/images/site_images/header-logo--full@2x.png" class ="nashPic" alt="Nash Community College" title="Nash Community College"
 width = "250px"/>
  <span class = "title">Nash Community College</span>
 </p>
</section>
```